# How to access data from ViewModel in ItemsSource tag

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext, itemssource

I'm making TabControl that can change dynamically using ItemsSource tag. 
I want to know the way to access ViewModel data in ItemsSource tag.

I searched through the Internet. but I couldn't find the answer.

**CODE**

```
public class ViewModel
{
      // this will be used in ItemsSource
      private ObservableCollection<ActiveButton> _allExecuteButtonInfos = new ObservableCollection<ActiveButton>();

      public ObservableCollection<ActiveButton> AllExecuteButtonInfos
      {
        get { return _allExecuteButtonInfos; }
        set {
            _allExecuteButtonInfos = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
      }

      // I want to get this data in ItemsSource
      private List<string> _boardNameList = new List<string>();

      public string BoardNameList
      {
          get { return _boardNameList; }
          set {
              _boardNameList = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
   <TabControl Background="#FF292929" ItemsSource="{Binding AllExecuteButtonInfos}">                     
          <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                      <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
                          <ComboBox Width="334" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                   <!-- I want to get data from ViewModel not in ItemsSource(AllExecuteButtonInfos) -->
                                   <!-- eg) VM:BoardNameList, ViewModel.BoardNameList etc -->
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding BoardNameList, Mode=TwoWay , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
                                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedBoard, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                      </Grid>
                  </ScrollViewer>
               </DataTemplate>
          </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I hope I can find the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: It is called proxy binding described at https://code.4noobz.net/wpf-mvvm-proxy-binding/

Comment: I suggest that you read the article from @SirRufo . It's in my opinion very useful may help you to solve similar problems in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to the `DataContext`, i.e. the view model, of the parent `TabControl` using a `RelativeSource`:

```
    <ComboBox ... 
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.BoardNameList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TabControl}}" />
```

Note that it's pointless to set the `Mode` of an `ItemsSource` binding to `TwoWay` since the control never sets the property. It's also meaningless to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` in this case for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where you've defined the data context but I suppose that it's somewhere above the first 'Grid' markup. Something like this?

```
  <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Then you have to somehow refer to the Datacontext of the window. You can do it this way

```
<ComboBox                              
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.BoardNameList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" />
```

if the name of your view is not 'MainWindow', you have to change it to the view name where you have that code.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best ways is to create a `UserControl` for each model and then put data templates in `TabControl.Resources` with `DataType` specified for all types you could put in ItemsSource - you get full customization of the view with nice seperation of XAML files.

```
<Grid>
   <TabControl Background="#FF292929" ItemsSource="{Binding AllExecuteButtonInfos}">                     
          <TabControl.Resources>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyViewModel1}">
                   <MyViewModel1_View ViewModel="{Binding}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
              <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyViewModel2}">
                   <MyViewModel2_View ViewModel="{Binding}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </TabControl.Resources>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

I'm going from memory, so the binding may be done differently, but that's the basic idea.

That, or you use some kind of `ViewResolver` as the only item in the TabControl (something like [this](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-location/))

Basically, go even more MVVM :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the `DataContext` of your view is set correctly to your `ViewModel` and `AllExecuteButtonInfos` is indeed available in your view, you can use a `RelativeBinding` to access properties which are not in the `DataContext` of your current scope.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.BoardNameList}" />
```

With that, you are leaving the implicit `DataContext` of the `DataTemplate`, which is `ActiveButton` and access the object of the specified type via `AncestorType`. From there you can set a `Path` to the `DataContext` of the `UserControl`, which is, in your case, an object of the class `ViewModel`.

Imaging you are climbing up a ladder. From the `ComboBox` object up to your `UserControl`, from where you can access all underlying properties.